# Something that bothers my intuitive thinking

Tags: standard-deviation

Here is an interesting situation I came along recently:

#### Turnover

- January: 5 million
- February: 6 million

#### Cost of goods sold (CoGS)

- January: 2 million
- February: 4 million

If we look at the relative percentages of CoGS from turnover we get 40% in January and 66.6% in February or an average of them of 53.3%.
If we look at the total for the two months we have a total of 11 million turnover and 5 million CoGS thus 54.54% of CoGS from sales.

I know averaging percentages is not indicated but my question is, is there a way to actually calculate that 54.54%-53.3% = 1.24% change beforehand?

Thanks!
I hope my question is not too ambiguous.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is clear.  What do you mean by "beforehand?"  What are you trying to actually calculate?

Comment: I am wondering if there is a formula for calculating that percentage 1.24%.

Comment: Err, you calculated it. How did you do that? You used a formula. But "beforehand" is confusing me, as it did @StatsStudent.  Before what?  Also, if you want to average percentages with different denominators you can use the harmonic mean; I wrote a [blog post about it ](https://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/measures-of-central-tendency-the-harmonic-mean/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are really just looking for a "formula" as you stated in your comment, this is derived just as you have.

The formula would just be:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{c_{1}+c_{2}}{t_{1}+t_{2}}-\frac{\frac{c_{1}}{t_{1}}+\frac{c_{2}}{t_{2}}}{2} & = & \frac{c_{1}+c_{2}}{t_{1}+t_{2}}-\frac{t_{2}c_{1}+t_{1}c_{2}}{2t_{1}t_{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}

where $t_i$ and $c_i$ are the turnover and cost of goods sold respectively at time $i=1,2$.

So for example, with R code:

```
> c <- c(2,4)
> t <- c(5,6)
> 100*(sum(c)/sum(t)-mean(c/t))
[1] 1.212121
```

or

```
> 100*(sum(c)/sum(t)-(t[2]*c[1]+t[1]*c[2])/(2*t[1]*t[2]))
[1] 1.212121
```